How can I setText() inbetween sequential animations of TextView object?
I have a TextView that I'd like to slide out of screen, then change the text, then slide back into view.  I have the animation in xml..
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="100%p"
        android:duration="700" />
</set>

..and similarly swipe_left.xml.
So far, in my MainActivity I have..
TextView view = findViewById(R.id.status_text);
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_right);
view.startAnimation(animation);
view.setText(status_text);
animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_left);
view.startAnimation(animation);

However, the second animation quickly cancels the first.  I've seen tutorial on how to chain them sequentially but I need to change the text in between animation.

Use an AnimationListener to be notified of onAnimationEnd and in that method put the remainder of your code - ie setText, loadAnimation, etc.  The listener is set using the Animation.setAnimationListener - do this prior to first starting the animation obviously.

Thanks, I literally just finished answering my own question with that.

What I did was set an onAnimationListener on the first animation and then setText() and second animation defined in the onAnimationEnd callback.
Animation animationL = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_right);
animationL.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        view.setText(status_text);
        Animation animationR = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slide_left);
        view.startAnimation(animationR);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
    });

view.startAnimation(animationL);

